# Is there dojo.hitch equivalent in node.js

Tags: node.js, dojo

I am looking for a function that kind bind the 'this' of a function. Although it is easy to write one, I want to be sure that it is not part of any popular module in node.js environment before I write or use the one from dojo.

Answer (score 7):

```
(function() {
  alert(this.toString());
}).bind(new String("Man ES5 is awesome.")).call();
```

[`Function.prototype.bind`<sup>*[docs]*</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Node.js runs on V8. V8 is fully ES5 compliant.